# How to sort results from `list-tasks` in aws-cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-cli, amazon-ecs

I have few tasks running i want to get the latest(task which started last, with last created-at) task arn.
I am using this command

```sh
aws ecs list-tasks --cluster {cluster} --family {family} --desired-status 'STOPPED'
```

after exploring a little i got to know about `sort_by`. I tried

```sh
aws ecs list-tasks --cluster {cluster} --family {family} --desired-status 'STOPPED' --query "sort_by(taskArns, &CreatedAt)"
```

But this gives error

```
In function sort_by(), invalid type for value: <some_task_arn>, expected one of: ['string', 'number'], received: "null"
```

Comment: "Last" by what measure? Last in the array returned form `list-tasks`, or last task created, or last task stopped?

Comment: by last i mean the task which started the last...whose `created time` is latest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list-tasks` will not give you that information. Have to use both `list-tasks` and `describe-tasks`.

I will provide **example on my cluster**, with `RUNNING` state tasks. You will **have to adjust it to your need**.

**1. Get the list of tasks**

```
task_arns=$(aws ecs list-tasks --cluster ${cluster[Name]} \
               --desired-status 'RUNNING' \
               --query 'taskArns' --output text)

echo ${task_arns}
```

Should give a list of Arns of your tasks, e.g.:

```
arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:275795381673:task/0053c603-a6c9-4044-89f5-b0edc8f6de3f arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:275795381673:task/0b4626ea-0f2b-4c99-9e90-010e8a0c8ad3 arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:275795381673:task/0d4aa5f2-f547-45ad-b1f8-ed84ef1d678c arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:275795381673:task/190a320f-4b68-497a-921e-439460447d45 arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:275795381673:task/c979f4a2-3665-4c56-93c6-e9b88f6b3519
```

**2. Get sorted tasks Arns**

```
aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster ${cluster[Name]} \
    --tasks  ${task_arns} \
    --query "tasks[] | reverse(sort_by(@, &createdAt)) | [].[createdAt,taskArn]" \
    --output table
```

Should give, eg:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                           DescribeTasks                                          |
+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1589888493.15 |  arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:275795381673:task/c979f4a2-3665-4c56-93c6-e9b88f6b3519   |
|  1589888501.348|  arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:275795381673:task/190a320f-4b68-497a-921e-439460447d45   |
|  1589888499.438|  arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:275795381673:task/0d4aa5f2-f547-45ad-b1f8-ed84ef1d678c   |
|  1589888500.312|  arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:275795381673:task/0b4626ea-0f2b-4c99-9e90-010e8a0c8ad3   |
|  1589888497.701|  arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:275795381673:task/0053c603-a6c9-4044-89f5-b0edc8f6de3f   |
+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**3. Get last element sorted tasks Arns**

```
aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster ${cluster[Name]} \
    --tasks  ${task_arns} \
    --query "tasks[] | reverse(sort_by(@, &createdAt)) | [-1].[taskArn]" \
    --output text
```

Should give:

```
arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:275795381673:task/0053c603-a6c9-4044-89f5-b0edc8f6de3f
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you work from a Linux/Unix-Shell I would suggest sending the output to the sort command. This works by adding

`| sort`

to your command at the end of the line:

```
aws ecs list-tasks --cluster {cluster} --family {family} --desired-status 'STOPPED' | sort
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I want to sort it by the time they `created-at`. This will sort according to the name i guess.